# "origin" pronunciation in the word "originate"

Tags: pronunciation

Why is the first part of the word `originate` pronounced differently than the standalone word `origin`?

```
origin    = /ˈôrəjən/
originate = /əˈrijəˌnāt/
```

Comment: Are you asking about the stress (first syllable, versus second syllable), or about the vowels (ô and ə versus ə and i)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Specific endings are often associated with specific stress patterns in English. Verbs ending in *-ate* that have three syllables or more are mostly stressed on the third-to-last syllable. (The last syllable has an unreduced vowel, and may be described in some theories as having a “minor” or “tertiary” stress.) Only vowels in fully unstressed syllables may be reduced to schwa, so in "origin" the second but not the first vowel may be reduced while in "originate" the first but not the second vowel may be reduced.